# Add a timestamp overlay using ffmpeg by Node Js

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am working on video editing. Currently I want to add time stamp on a video. I have found some command line code from a website. But how can I add this by Node Js FFMPEG module.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920" -vf "drawtext=fontfile=arial.ttf:text='%m';fontcolor=white@0.8:x=7:y=460" -vcodec libx264 -vb 2000k -preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4
```

Some notes: arial.tff lives in the same directory as ffmpeg

[Here](http://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/) is the website link.

Comment: Hi, Can you mention in fiddle?

Comment: You can use this : .videoFilters({ 
filter: 'drawtext',
 options: { 
fontfile: 'Lucida Grande.ttf',
 text: 'THIS IS TEXT', /* etc. */ 
} });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to add Title on video.

Here the code :

```
.videoFilters({ 
filter: 'drawtext',
 options: { 
fontfile: 'Lucida Grande.ttf',
 text: 'THIS IS TEXT', /* etc. */ 
} });
```